# how to refresh QTableWidget cells, after changing back-ground color

Tags: qt, qt5.1

I have a matrix created by QTableWidget, I have multiple threads that changing the colors of the cells, I want to see the coloring changing immediately after setting the color.
what I have now is that only after finishing all cells coloring I see the whole cells colors changed as once.
I have a good delay between the coloring, so it's not that the threads are filling the cells so fast.

every thread calls the function 
`fillInCell(x,y,val,myThreadIdx);`

```
void ResultMatrix::fillInCell(int i, int j, int val, int color )
{

    QTableWidgetItem* item = new QTableWidgetItem();
    item->setText(QString::number(val));
    colorCell(color,item);
    ui->matrixResult->setItem(i,j,item);
}
```

and colorCell is the function that color cells

```
void ResultMatrix::colorCell(int threadNum, QTableWidgetItem* item)
{

    switch (threadNum)
    {
    case 0:{
            QColor cellColor(255, 0, 0 );
            item->setBackgroundColor(cellColor);
            return;}
    case 1:{
.....
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please show your code that reproduces the issue.

Comment: added, tell me if you want more code to be added

Comment: try with `QCoreApplication::processEvents()` before `return`

Answer (score 0):

The method worked for me:

```
QAbstractItemView::reset();
```

[QTableWidget](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html) inherits after [QAbstractItemView](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html)