# QTableWidget - refresh cell when application is running

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt4, qtablewidget

I have got app which check date (linux) and put this 'date' into the cell 'a1'.
How to refresh cell 'a1' after one minute when application is running ?
In the future I will refresh all cells listed below but in the beginning is good to know how to refresh the first one ;]
Application will be running under linux (not windows).

```
import sys 
import os

from PyQt4.QtCore import * 
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

#!/usr/bin/python

a1 = os.popen("date")
a1 = a1.read()

data = {'date':['%s'%a1,'a2','a3'], 'x1':['b1','b2','b3'], 'x2':['c1','c2','c3'], 'x3':['d1','d2','d3'], 'x4':['e1','e2','e3'], 'min':['f1','f2','f3'], 'x5':['g1','g2','g3'], 'x6':['h1','h2','h3']}

class MyTable(QTableWidget): 

    def __init__(self, data, *args): 
        QTableWidget.__init__(self, *args) 
        self.data = data 
        self.setmydata()
        self.resizeColumnsToContents() 
        self.resizeRowsToContents()

    def setmydata(self):
        horHeaders = []
        for n, key in enumerate(sorted(self.data.keys())):  
          horHeaders.append(key) 
          for m, item in enumerate(self.data[key]): 
               newitem = QTableWidgetItem(item) 
               self.setItem(m, n, newitem) 
         self.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(horHeaders)


    def main(args): 
        app = QApplication(args) 
        table = MyTable(data, 5, 8) 
        table.show() 
        sys.exit(app.exec_())   

if __name__=="__main__": 
    main(sys.argv)
```

Comment: You might be more interested in implementing this with the model/view method using a QTableView and QAbstractTabelModel instead of a QTableWidget. When using model/view if the data changes, the display changes. When doing it with a QTableWidget you have to do a lot of extra "connecting" which might get annoying as your code grows.

Comment: thx for that, my next question is do I need a button for example 'update' to refresh data in table or it can be done automatically in the background ? I am talking about QAbstractTabelModel

Comment: When using a QAbstractTabelModel, as long as you set it up correctly, when the data changes the display should change as well. Take a look at this [tutorial](http://www.yasinuludag.com/blog/?p=98), I found it really helpful when first trying to understand models and views in PyQt4

Comment: One more thing! You have this
    `from PyQt4.QtCore import * 
    from PyQt4.QtGui import *
    from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui`
in your code. I would advise to only use the last one and prefix the things you want with `QtGui.Foo()` or `QtCore.Bar()`. This is pretty standard in most PyQt programs!

Comment: Here you have answer for C++: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21073841/how-to-refresh-qtablewidget-cells-after-changing-back-ground-color/49408147#49408147, similar function should be for python